# Extend System.Data.Objects 3.5 methods for 4.0 (such as IObjectSet, CreateObjectSet,ContextOptions

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to extend the System.Data.Objects 3.5 version to include some System.Data.Objects .Net 4.0 methods (such as IObjectSet, CreateObjectSet,ContextOptions).  I am forced to target 3.5 in a Sharepoint 2010 project, using EF v 1.  My Repository was built in .Net 4.0, shown below.  How can I either correct this to work in 3.5, or extend the System.Data.Objects 3.5 class so that the new 4.0 methods will be consumed:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
using Workflowportal_LINQDAL.Repository.Interface;
using Workflowportal_LINQDAL.Repository.Specification;

namespace Workflowportal_LINQDAL.Repository.Repository
{
    public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        private ObjectContext _context;
        private readonly IObjectSet<TEntity> _objectSet;

        public Repository(ObjectContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _objectSet = _context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
            //_context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true; Default!
        }

        public Repository(ObjectContext context, bool lazyLoading)
        {
            _context = context;
            _objectSet = _context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
            _context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = lazyLoading;
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        //public void SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
        //{
        //    _context.SaveChanges(options);
        //}

        public void AcceptAllChanges()
        {
            _context.AcceptAllChanges();
        }

        public void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }

            _objectSet.AddObject(entity);
        }

        public void Edit(TEntity entity)
        {
            _objectSet.Attach(entity);
            _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
        }

        public void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }

            _objectSet.DeleteObject(entity);
        }
        public void Delete(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            var records = Find(predicate);

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                Delete(record);
            }
        }

        public void Delete(ISpecification<TEntity> specification)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DeleteRelatedEntities(TEntity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }

            var releatedEntities =
                ((IEntityWithRelationships)entity).RelationshipManager.GetAllRelatedEnds().SelectMany(
                    e => e.CreateSourceQuery().OfType<TEntity>()).ToList();
            foreach (var releatedEntity in releatedEntities)
            {
                _objectSet.DeleteObject(releatedEntity);
            }
            _objectSet.DeleteObject(entity);

        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _objectSet.AsEnumerable();
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllQuery()
        {
            return _objectSet.AsQueryable();
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAllPaged(int page, int pageSize)
        {
            return _objectSet.AsEnumerable().Skip(pageSize).Take(page);
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _objectSet.Where(predicate).AsEnumerable();
        }

        public IQueryable<TEntity> FindQuery(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _objectSet.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(ISpecification<Func<TEntity, bool>> specification)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IEnumerable<TEntity> FindPaged(int page, int pageSize, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _objectSet.Where(predicate).Skip(pageSize).Take(page).AsEnumerable();
        }

        public TEntity Single(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _objectSet.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
        }

        public TEntity Single(ISpecification<Func<TEntity, bool>> specification)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public TEntity First(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _objectSet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
        }

        public TEntity First(ISpecification<Func<TEntity, bool>> specification)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int Count()
        {
            return _objectSet.Count();
        }

        public int Count(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> criteria)
        {
            return _objectSet.Count(criteria);
        }

        public int Count(ISpecification<TEntity> specification)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #region IDisposable
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposing) return;
            if (_context == null) return;
            _context.Dispose();
            _context = null;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try as below which is for .Net 3.5

```
namespace Microsoft.Samples.Entity
{

    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for SalesOrdersEntities in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SalesOrdersEntities : global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new SalesOrderEntities object using the connection string found in the 'SalesOrderEntities' section of the application configuration file.
        /// </summary>
        public SalesOrdersEntities() :
            base("name=SalesOrdersEntities", "SalesOrdersEntities")
        {
            this.OnContextCreated();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new SalesOrderEntities object.
        /// </summary>
        public SalesOrdersEntities(string connectionString) :
            base(connectionString, "SalesOrdersEntities")
        {
            this.OnContextCreated();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize a new SalesOrderEntities object.
        /// </summary>
        public SalesOrdersEntities(global::System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection connection) :
            base(connection, "SalesOrdersEntities")
        {
            this.OnContextCreated();
        }
        partial void OnContextCreated();
        /// <summary>
        /// There are no comments for LineItemSet in the schema.
        /// </summary>
        public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<LineItem> LineItemSet
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this._LineItemSet == null))
                {
                    this._LineItemSet = base.CreateQuery<LineItem>("[LineItemSet]");
                }
                return this._LineItemSet;
            }
        }
        private global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<LineItem> _LineItemSet;
        /// <summary>
        /// There are no comments for OrderSet in the schema.
        /// </summary>
        public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Order> OrderSet
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this._OrderSet == null))
                {
                    this._OrderSet = base.CreateQuery<Order>("[OrderSet]");
                }
                return this._OrderSet;
            }
        }
        private global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Order> _OrderSet;
        /// <summary>
        /// There are no comments for LineItemSet in the schema.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToLineItemSet(LineItem lineItem)
        {
            base.AddObject("LineItemSet", lineItem);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// There are no comments for OrderSet in the schema.
        /// </summary>
        public void AddToOrderSet(Order order)
        {
            base.AddObject("OrderSet", order);
        }
    }
}
```